# Visual basic 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll error

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I'm trying to make a code to get the IP GEO information.

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Xml
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub geo()
    Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList
    Dim i As Integer
    xmldoc.Load("http://freegeoip.cnet/xml/" & TextBox1.Text)// this is where I get the Error
    xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Respon­se")
    For i = 0 To xmlnode.Count - 1
        Label1.Text = "IP Address : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()
        Label2.Text = "Country Code : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()
        Label3.Text = "Country Name : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim()
        Label4.Text = "Region Code : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim()
        Label5.Text = "Region Name : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText.Trim()
        Label6.Text = "City : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText.Trim()
        Label7.Text = "Zip Code : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(5).InnerText.Trim()
        Label8.Text = "Latitude : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(6).InnerText.Trim()
        Label9.Text = "Longitude : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(7).InnerText.Trim()
        Label10.Text = "Metro Code : " & xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(8).InnerText.Trim()
        xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(9).InnerText.Trim()

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    geo()
End Sub
End Class
```

and this is the error message:

> 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Please show the *full* stack trace including the error message. Exceptions have *much* more to them than just the name of the type...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this programming thing

how to get that full stack trace?

Comment: Well we don't know where you're seeing the error at all - but I'd expect it to be there. (Hint: if you convert this into a short but complete console app, including the full URL, the code will be shorter, we'll be able to reproduce it, *and* when running it you'll see the full stack trace...)

Comment: Decorate a try..catch around the xmldoc.Load and check for textbox1 value.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the correct parameters to the website.  Below is an example of data returned from freegeoip.

```
Imports System.Xml
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String =
            "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & _
               "<Response>" & _
                  "<IP>123.123.123.123</IP>" & _
                  "<CountryCode>CN</CountryCode>" & _
                  "<CountryName>China</CountryName>" & _
                  "<RegionCode>11</RegionCode>" & _
                  "<RegionName>Beijing Shi</RegionName>" & _
                  "<City>Beijing</City>" & _
                  "<ZipCode/>" & _
                  "<TimeZone>Asia/Shanghai</TimeZone>" & _
                  "<Latitude>39.929</Latitude>" & _
                  "<Longitude>116.388</Longitude>" & _
                  "<MetroCode>0</MetroCode></Response>"
        Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument
        xmldoc.LoadXml(input)

    End Sub

End Module​
```